# How to use subquery within a case statement?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables .

table1

```
t1id var1 var2
1    xxx   ccc
2    ccc   ddd
3    eee   bbb
```

table2

```
t2id attribute 
1    lll  
3    ggg
4    ggg
5    lll
```

I need to select * from table1, and concatenate `t1id` with `attribute` if `t1id=t2id`

Here is what I tried

```
SEL CASE WHEN (t1id IN (SELECT t2id FROM table2) ) 
    THEN t1id || attribute 
    ELSE t1id END AS t1idModified,
var1 , var2
FROM table1,table2
```

However, it did not work . How can I use a subquery within case?

Answer (score 0):

Even if this syntax was allowed it would not return the expected result.

What's the datatype of `t1id`, numeric or string?

You can rewrite it as an Outer Join (return a row even if there's no match) and a COALESCE (concat the attribute or ''):

```
SELECT
   TRIM(t1.t1id) || (COALESCE(t2.ATTRIBUTE, '')) AS t1idModified,
   var1, var2
FROM table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2
ON t1.t1id = t2.t2id
```